# Повторная генерация исключения в C++

Tags: c++, исключения

Не совсем понимаю, почему в следующем коде происходит обрезка объекта класса Child.

```
#include <iostream>

class Parent
{
public:
    Parent() { }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Parent"; }
};

class Child: public Parent
{
public:
    Child() { }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Child"; }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            throw Child();
        }
        catch (Parent& p)
        {
            std::cout << "Caught Parent p, which is actually a ";
            p.print();
            std::cout << std::endl;
            // обрезка объекта класса Child происходит здесь
            throw p;
        }
    }
    catch (Parent& p)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught Parent p, which is actually a ";
        p.print();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

В итоге мы получим следующий вывод, который подтверждает, что происходит обрезка:

*Caught Parent p, which is actually a Child*
*Caught Parent p, which is actually a Parent*

Я знаю, что если вместо `throw p;` написать `throw;`, то компилятор будет использовать точно тот же самый объект в повторном исключении (без копирования), и мы получим следующий вывод:

*Caught Parent p, which is actually a Child*
*Caught Parent p, which is actually a Child*

Comment: Так вы сами, в общем-то, на свой вопрос практически и ответили. В первом блоке catch параметр p имеет тип ссылки на Parent и при использовании виртуальных методов вызывается метод print класса Child, при исполнении кода `throw p;` создается копия (по сути, вызывается конструктор копирования, а так как он не виртуальный (и не может им быть), то созданная копия - объект класса Parent.

Comment: Этот код даже не соберется, так как конструкторы и все методы приватные.

Comment: @user7860670 поправил

Comment: @АлексейСаровский Просто я думал, что вызывается конструктор копирования, который копирует в том числе скрытый указатель *__vptr (назову его так) на виртуальную таблицу, в которой записан адрес на Child::print(). Но на деле это не так

Comment: Тогда тут другая проблема - все конструкторы неявные.

Comment: А если бы копировался указатель на таблицу виртуальных функций, то это был бы веселый зашквар когда эти функции обращались бы к полям производного класса.

Comment: Здесь `throw p;` создаётся и инициализируется новый объект. Тип этого объекта определяется _статическим_ типом выражения `p`. В данном случае этот тип —  `Parent`. Т.е. происходит что-то вроде такого: `Parent temp_object = p;`. И дальше этот `temp_object` выступает в качестве объекта исключения.

Comment: Сложно что-то добавить к тому, что вы сами видите. Да, `throw` не смотрит, показывает ссылка на потомка или нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допишем пару конструкторов

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Parent
{
public:
    Parent() { cout << "Parent::Parent()\n"; }
    Parent(const Parent&) { cout << "Parent::Parent(const Parent&)\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Parent"; }
};

class Child: public Parent
{
public:
    Child() { cout << "Child::Child()\n"; }
    Child(const Child& ) { cout << "Child::Child(const Child&)\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Child"; }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        try
        {
            throw Child();
        }
        catch (Parent& p)
        {
            std::cout << "Caught Parent p, which is actually a ";
            p.print();
            std::cout << std::endl;
            // обрезка объекта класса Child происходит здесь
            throw p;
        }
    }
    catch (Parent& p)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught Parent p, which is actually a ";
        p.print();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

и вывод

```
Parent::Parent()
Child::Child()
Caught Parent p, which is actually a Child
Parent::Parent(const Parent&)
Caught Parent p, which is actually a Parent
```

ясно продемонстрирует, что при `throw p;` генерируется *копия* объекта `Parent`.

Что и поясняет наблюдаемое поведение.

Comment: Кто виноват - выяснили, а что делать? Как добиться желаемого вывода? Как скопировать таблицу виртуальных методов в конструкторе копирования?

Comment: @maestro Ну, можно проверить через `dynamic_cast`, не `Child` ли это на самом деле, и использовать соответствующий конструктор. А вообще, если у вас написано `f(Parent p)`, вы же миритесь со срезкой при передаче аргумента?